# Emails do not reach their recipient

Tags: email, html-email, webmail

I have migrated my managed site by cPanel to another server that is also managed by cPanel, the problem I am having is that I try to send an email from my new host with one of my accounts and the mail never reaches its destination.

The problem occurs when within the body of the message I include images or urls of my site, for example:

If I include a `<a href='https://example.com/register'>url</a>` tag the mail never reaches its destination, also if I include something like `<img src='https://mywebsite.com/images/logo.png'>` these emails never reach their destination, but if I remove these labels the email reaches the destination without problems.

It should be noted that before the migration the mail service worked without problems.

Any suggestions or solutions to this problem?

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it's off-topic here. That said, there are whole companies specializing in email delivery. It boils down to not sending anything that looks like spam, and sending from a trusted IP address. I guess the later has changed for you. You can warm up your IP address by slowing down your sending and hence getting mail providers to know and trust you. Also keep in mind that emails may be delayed and may either bounce or get through after a few days.

Comment: I have already made DKIM, SPF and other configurations, ensuring that everything is correct but the problem persists, it is fine that it is not a development problem but it affects the sending of automatic notifications that my platform sends through email